# How to show the subpages of a page using navigation rendering in Sitecore 9.0.1?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 . I have created a partial design page in that i have added a Navigation component to my page and in the Page it is showing all the pages which are to be displayed on the navbar but it is not displaying the links of sub pages of the page in the navbar.

This is the component in the partial design page:

[image]

Control Properties:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please explain how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: did you try looking at this after publishing your changes or in preview mode? All the navigation items should have a link by default.

Comment: Is the navigation not showing the subpages or are they shown without a link?